# Can't install SDK in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I’m trying to install a SDK for Laravel PHP and get this error:

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for e-nikitin/yclients-laravel-sdk ^0.3.10 -> satisfiable by e-nikitin/yclients-laravel-sdk[v0.3.10].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.26.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.26.0
    - e-nikitin/yclients-laravel-sdk v0.3.10 requires illuminate/support ^5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev].
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.5.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.0
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.0
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.0
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.0
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.4.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v7.26.0, required as ^7.26) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.26.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Link to SDK: https://github.com/e-nikitin/yclients-laravel-sdk

Comment: And what's your question about this? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this package only supports Laravel `>=5.4 | <6.x`

You are using Laravel 7.x, which is not supported by the package.